# Kubuntu 17.04 freezes every 20s for a second

Tags: drivers, kubuntu, xorg, kde, plasma-5

Every ~20 seconds Kubuntu 17.04 system freezes (screen, mouse, keyboard, sound output) I was trying to determine a process in `htop` and `iotop`, without success. There's no process with significant IO/CPU usage.

I'm running on `4.10.0-30-generic` with nvidia GPU. I've already tried switching between different nvidia binary drivers `384`, `378`, `xorg-noveau` also without any impact (open source drivers).

I'm using drivers from graphics repository:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu zesty main
```

the graphics card is `Quadro 4000`, but I've reproduced same behaviour on different nvidia card.

```
$ lspci |grep VGA
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF100GL [Quadro 4000] (rev a3)
```

Currently the display manager is set to `sddm`. Switching to `lightdm` didn't make any difference.

Any idea how to debug this issue? I haven't noticed any suspicious messages in `syslog`, end of `dmesg` ([whole `dmesg` output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/25270141/))

```
[ 1021.105773] usb 3-2: cannot submit urb (err = -27)
[ 1021.105777] usb 3-2: cannot submit urb (err = -27)
[ 1021.105780] usb 3-2: cannot submit urb (err = -27)
[ 1118.607240] perf: interrupt took too long (2504 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 79750
[ 1402.192086] usb 3-2: cannot submit urb (err = -27)
[ 1537.168514] usb 3-2: cannot submit urb (err = -27)
[ 1537.168520] usb 3-2: cannot submit urb (err = -27)
[ 1537.168524] usb 3-2: cannot submit urb (err = -27)
[ 1537.168527] usb 3-2: cannot submit urb (err = -27)
[ 2412.218572] perf: interrupt took too long (3132 > 3130), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 63750
[ 7381.257550] usb 3-2: cannot submit urb (err = -27)
```

At the beginning of `dmesg` there's following message:

```
[    0.095599] DMAR-IR: This system BIOS has enabled interrupt remapping
               on a chipset that contains an erratum making that
               feature unstable.  To maintain system stability
               interrupt remapping is being disabled.  Please
               contact your BIOS vendor for an update
```

According to [Suse guide](https://www.novell.com/support/kb/doc.php?id=7014344) such message concerns certain Intel chipsets:

```
lspci -nn | grep -qE '8086:(340[36].*rev 13|3405.*rev (12|13|22))' && echo "Interrupt remapping is broken"
```

I seem to have one of the broken chipsets, so I've added kernel parameter

```
intremap=off
```

the `dmesg` message is gone, yet the problem persists. I've narrowed down the cause to the graphic card drivers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After observing running processes I've realized, that display freezing correlates with `plasmashell` process utilizing CPU. Removing all widgets from desktop resolved the issue.

The problem was probably cased by Thermal Monitor widget. Or combination with other widgets.